# Doctrine2 Lazy vs Eager, or why it makes multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, oop, symfony, doctrine-orm

So I am using QueryBuilder in some of my projects, but others I need to create RAW SQL queries in order to increase performance, as I have more than a million rows with their relations...

What I found awful about QueryBuilder, is the fact that it creates several queries when you have relations, for example, I have a `OneToMany` relation from `Product` to `Image` and a `ManyToOne` on the inversed side.

My query has a pagination, so it is limited to `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0` and on. My `Image` entity has about 2.7 million rows, that's why I am using pagination, doing this simple query, which fetches `Image i` plus `Product p` because I need `p.title` I end up with 1 Query for my 10 images, and 10 queries for each `Product` for `Image`.

That's unneeded, It can be done with just 2 queries, one for `Image` and one for `Product`, using `fetch="EAGER"` that's what I get. But I need to put `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"` inside `Product` mapping, otherwise I will get 11 queries again..

With just 10 images isn't hard, but when the user filters 500 images, response time gets higher and higher... That's why I've ended up doing RAW queries, best performance, no extra queries (just 1 query that contains everything) BUT unable to work with objects like QueryBuilder does, can't access to `image.product.title` inside twig to get the title, instead I need to do `SELECT p.title AS product_title` and call `image.product_title` etc

So I need to know why QueryBuilder is that sh*t when reading but so marvelous when persisting objects (easy, fast, clean...) and how can I work with huge DB's using QueryBuilder without loosing performance and without getting tons of extra unneeded queries.

An example query, is this one

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
$qb->innerJoin('i.product', 'p');
$qb->where('i.X = Y');
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult()
```

Using `$qb->select('i, p');` seems to use only one query, which it's runnable raw has an INNER JOIN (which is actually how it is supossed to work WITHOUT the  `$qb->select()`) but performance is still lower than doing a RAW SQL query... RAW SQL = 500MS for a 10.000 rows query, using QB it's 1,100 MS. I know I wont use 10.000 rows, but there's a chance...

The question is still the same, what advantages and disadvantages, besides the object manipulation, which is gone with a RAW SQL. And when to use LAZY or EAGER and WHY, or why/when you don't need them.

All of this may end a discussion in my DevTeam once for all. As I'm a QB lover.

Comment: The Update vs Read mismatch is well known.  Might want to research  Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html.  Your best solution might be a mixture of qb and sql.

Comment: And to make your 10,000 row benchmark useful, you need to dump all those records to html and then bring them up in a browser.  As you probably know, the extra 600ms needed for the query would be lost in the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do something like this:

```
SELECT i FROM AcmeBundle:Image i JOIN i.product p WHERE ...
```

?

That would explain numerous queries because `Doctrine` does not preserve fetched data.

Doing something like this tells `Doctrine` to actually preserve fetched data of both `Image` and `Product`:

```
SELECT i, p FROM AcmeBundle:Image i JOIN i.product p WHERE ...
```

Then, you would have no need neither for `EAGER` nor `EAGER_LAZY`.

I might have missed the point in your question. If I have, please correct me and I might be able to suggesting something else.

### Edit:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
$qb->innerJoin('i.product', 'p');
$qb->addSelect('p'); // Very importang, hints Doctrine to preserve fetched Product
$qb->where('i.X = Y');
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult()
```

Or using `PARTIAL`:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
$qb->innerJoin('i.product', 'p');
$qb->select('PARTIAL i.{image_field1, image_field2}', 'PARTIAL p.{product_field1, product_field2}'); // Very importang, hints Doctrine to preserve fetched Product
$qb->where('i.X = Y');
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult()
```

Comment: I've updated my question. I've tried with select i,p inside querybuilder, it reduces my queries but the performance is still lower than raw SQL...

Comment: Most definitely :( Nothing compares to raw SQL. You might be able to squeeze some more using `PARTIAL` fetching...

Comment: I totally forgot about `PARTIAL` :P I used looong time ago for last time, but yes, it's improving Performance significantly choosing only fields I will use. So, can you tell me if it's worst using QueryBuilder than RAW? Because there is some people telling me that, only because they wanted to fetch tons of data with bad mappings

Comment: It's definitely more convinient to fetch objects (`QueryBuilder`). So, if you need to iterate over the fetched collection and do something, that is preferable way. But for simple `REST` API, or if you want more performance, that might just not be the case :)